# Laravel named route pass variable

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to pass variable to a named route:

```
return redirect()->route('Company.Dashboard.Subscription.Index')->with(compact('message'));
```

But in blade i cant access the message variable.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
return redirect()->route('Company.Dashboard.Subscription.Index')->with('variable message name','your message here');
```

Or:

```
return redirect('your route')->with('variable message name','your message here');
```

Comment: return redirect()->route('Company.Dashboard.Subscription.Index')->with('message','your message here');  and in blade {{$message}}, but i get an error Undefined variable: message

Comment: no no, in blade you have to access via session: 
{{Session::get("message")}}